# Definition of the rank of an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, abelian-groups

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_abelian_group), the **rank** of an abelian group $G$ is the size of the largest free abelian group contained in $G$. So, is the rank of $G$ equal to:
$$\sup \{|F|\mid {F\text{ is a subgroup of }G\text{, }F\text{ is a free abelian group} }\}$$
?

here, $|F|$ is the cardinality of $F$.

I'm looking for a symbolic definition in general case. What is meant by **largest** in wikipedia?

Comment: No. The rank of $\Bbb Z^r$ is $r$. For a finitely generated abelian group $G$, you can define it as $\mathrm{rk}(G) = \dim_{\Bbb Q}(G \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb Q)$.

Comment: @Watson I want a symbolic definition in general case. What is meant by *largest* in wikipedia?

Comment: Largest in the sense of "containment".  In other words, a free abelian subgroup not contained in any other free abelian subgroups.

Comment: @SteveD So does the largest mean the [maximal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element) subgroup which is a free abelian group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what wikipedia says. It says the rank is the cardinality of a *maximal linearly independent subset*. Here, maximal means not properly contained in another linearly independent subset. Linearly independent is defined in the body of the entry: using additive notation, $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is a linearly independent set if
$$
a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n=0 \Rightarrow \forall i\;a_i=0
$$
where the $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the $x_i$ are elements of the group. An infinite subset is linearly independent if all of its finite subsets are. The wikipedia entry gives a reference to Lang's *Algebra*, but unfortunately Lang actually gives a different (though equivalent) definition of rank.

The main complicating factor, at least in the finitely generated case, are torsion elements, i.e., elements of finite order. However, any linearly independent set cannot contain any torsion elements, since $ax=0\Rightarrow a=0$ follows from linear independence, and this means that $x$ is not a torsion element.

Example: $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$. The set $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ is a maximal linearly independent set. There are others, for example $\{(2,0,0),(0,3,0)\}$, but they all have the same cardinality. (This is not completely trivial to prove, though it's not super-hard either, once you have enough background.)

The second sentence of the wikipedia entry says, "The rank of $A$ determines the size of the largest free abelian group contained in $A$."  This is not a definition. However, it is inspired by one:
$$
\text{rank }A = \max \{\dim F | F\text{ a free abelian subgroup of }A\}
$$
Of course we then need a definition for the dimension (aka rank) of a free abelian group. One definition: since the tensor product $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} F$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, just define $\dim F$ to be the vector space dimension of $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} F$.

Since tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ kills the torsion subgroup, the rank of $A$ is just $\dim \mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} A$; no need to look at the free abelian subgroups.

Comment: In fact I had copy pasted the second definition appearing in wikipedia page in my question. I'm more interested in a definition in terms of free abelian groups and I want to write it with symbols like the one in question so that it is more clear.

Comment: OK, I added a paragraph to respond to this.

Comment: Do you mean "The rank of $A$ determines the size of the largest free abelian group contained in $A$." is wrong?

Comment: Well, saying that "X determines Y" is not a *definition* of X. Also, talking about "the largest free abelian group contained in $A$" is sloppy: there isn't necessarily a unique maximal such group. (Example: $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't have *any* maximal free abelian subgroups. However, all the free abelian subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ have the same cardinality, namely $\aleph_0$.) There are ways to interpret the sentence that make it true. My guess is, the author intended it only to provide intuition, not as an alternate definition.

Comment: These are what I understood:

1) If in "The rank of AA determines the size of the largest free abelian group contained in AA", **largest** means **with greatest cardinality** then it is wrong.

2) If in "The rank of AA determines the size of the largest free abelian group contained in AA", **largest** means **maximal free abelian subgroup** then it is wrong (or incomplete) because there may not be any maximal subgroup.

Comment: 3) $rank(G)=\sup \{\dim(F)\mid {F\text{ is a subgroup of }G\text{, }F\text{ is a free abelian group} }\}$ where $\dim(F)$ is  the cardinality of a freely generating set for it.

Are these correct?

Comment: Your (3) is correct. As for the statements, what is meant by size? Suppose "size" means "cardinality". Then this statement is true: "The rank of $A$ determines the maximum possible cardinality of a free abelian subgroup of $A$. However, that cardinality does not determine the rank of $A$." Namely, if the rank of $A$ is finite and greater than 0, then that maximum cardinality is $\aleph_0$.